# Scan outgoing Postfix email for spam with Spamassassin

Tags: postfix, spamassasin, amavis

Is there a way to filter outgoing Postfix email for spam possibly with Spamassassin?

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/126282/postfix-check-outgoing-mail-for-spam) answer about how to do it with Amavis but it's terribly outdated and not very well explained.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/749257/scan-outgoing-postfix-email-for-spam-with-spamassassin